# Add the name of the file analyzed to the e-mail (logcheck)

Tags: linux, email, apache-2.4, logging

I use logcheck to receive apache logs. My question is how to configure logcheck to add the name of the file that is analysed in the email. Example: at the moment I have this:

> This email is sent by logcheck. If you no longer wish to receive this
> type of mail, you can either uninstall the logcheck package, or modify
> its configuration file (/etc). its configuration file
> (/etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf).
>
> System events =-=-=-=-=-=-= [Thu Oct 19 13:50:02.803949 2023]
> [evasive20:error] [pid 31123] [client 00.000.00.000:52017] client
> denied by server configuration: /path/to/site

I would like :

> This email is sent by logcheck. If you no longer wish to receive this
> type of mail, you can either uninstall the logcheck package, or modify
> its its configuration file (/etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf).
>
> System events File: site_error.log =-=-=-=-=-=-= [Thu Oct 19
> 13:50:02.803949 2023] [evasive20:error] [pid 31123] [client
> 00.000.00.000:52017] client denied by server configuration: /path/to/site

Thank you in advance for your help, Mehdi.

I tried to search for the basic email template but all I could find was the file /etc/logcheck/header.txt My idea would be to add a $FILENAME variable to the template if possible